# How to fix a ValueError for Dense layer input shape when training a CNN with tensorflow.data.datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tf.data.dataset

I am building a CNN using the Model class and I have encountered an error that when I switch from convolutional layers to dense layers, the model breaks and throws a value error.

My training data is a tf.data.Dataset (I am new to using this) and it seems to be ok, however when I try to fit the model it does not work. There is a ValueError saying that the Dense layer inputs need to have their last dimension defined, I thought it should inherit the shape from previous layers? I tried using the CIFAR10 dataset and it worked fine, however it doesn't for my dataset so I am very confused.

Any ideas or help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated!

My code is somewhat niche, but this is a summary of what I tried:

```
class CNN(Model):

    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        conv_arguments = dict(kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'relu')
        pool_arguments = dict(pool_size = (2,2))

        # convolutional layers
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, **conv_arguments, input_shape=input_shape)
        self.maxpool1 = MaxPooling2D(**pool_arguments)

        self.conv2 = Conv2D(48, **conv_arguments)
        self.maxpool2 = MaxPooling2D(**pool_arguments)

        self.conv3 = Conv2D(64, **conv_arguments)
        self.maxpool3 = MaxPooling2D(**pool_arguments)
        
        # flatten layer
        self.flatten = Flatten()

        # dense layers
        self.dense1 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')

        self.dropout = Dropout(0.2)

        self.dense2 = Dense(4, activation = 'sigmoid')

    def call(self, x):
        
        # layers are defined in __init__()

        # convolutional layers
        x = self.conv1(x)     # defined with an input shape (424, 424, 3)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.maxpool3(x)

        # flatten layer
        x = self.flatten(x)

        # dense layers
        x = self.dense1(x)

        # use dropout
        x = self.dropout(x)

        # final layer
        x = self.dense2(x)

        return x

...

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_files, train_labels))

# shuffle the data
train_data = train_data.shuffle(len(train_files))

# load the images and cache
train_data = train_data.map(lambda x, y: (load_image(x), y), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
train_data = train_data.cache().repeat()

# augment and batch the data
train_data = train_data.map(lambda x, y: (augmentation.call(x), y), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)

...

# create model, compile, and train
model = CNN(input_shape=(424, 424, 3)) # input shape so the class has image shape for 1st conv layer
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss_obj, metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1, callbacks = [early], validation_data = val_data, class_weight = data.class_weights, steps_per_epoch = nb_steps_per_epoch)
```

When I do this it starts epoch 1 and then throws the following error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)


    Call arguments received by layer "cnn" "                 f"(type CNN):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many nodes/units should be present in the Dense layer? It does take input shape from the previous layer but what about units/nodes/output shape? You can refer [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense). And I doubt it's a correct functional approach wrt provided code snippet.

Comment: The number of nodes is 64, this is defined in the Model __init__() (I realise I left this out by accident). I am following the structure defined in this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced

Comment: The code you posted does not really fit together. E.g. your definition of the `CNN` class takes no arguments in the constructor, but when you define `model` you are passing `input_shape`.

Comment: What is the definition of `augmentation.call` ?

Comment: augmentation is another model class object that has random augmentation layers. This model works with the tf.data.Dataset, although it is not trainable as it is just random flips, zooms, translations, rotations etc. So it has the same form as CNN call(self, x) just with different layers.